# Is is posible that $\int_{}^{}f(x)dx=F(x)+B+C$ where $C$ is the only integration constant and $f(x)\neq 0$? (WA bug?)

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

(I´m not an english native speaker so sorry if I don´t let my self be clear or write something wrong)

I was solving the last integral from [this bprp video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5MaGUO0JDs&t=33s&ab_channel=blackpenredpen) and got this answer:

$$\int_{}^{}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\arccos(x)+\sqrt{(1-x^2)}x\right)+C$$

instead of replacing $x$ with $\sin(u)$, I replaced it with $\cos(u)$ to see how the answer will change. However, [my answer is wrong according to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2Csqrt%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx%5D%3D-Divide%5B1%2C2%5D*%5C%2840%29ArcCos%5Bx%5D%2Bsqrt%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29*x%5C%2841%29&lang=es)

The thing is that my answer and WA´s answer only differs by a $+\pi/4$ in the end (if you see well both functions have the same "shape"). Matter fact if [I add a $+\pi/4$ my answer is correct according to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2Csqrt%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx%5D%3D-Divide%5B1%2C2%5D*%5C%2840%29ArcCos%5Bx%5D%2Bsqrt%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29*x%5C%2841%29%2BDivide%5Bpi%2C4%5D&lang=es)

(Answer from WA):

$$\int_{}^{}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\arccos(x)+\sqrt{(1-x^2)}x\right)+\pi/4+C$$

Shouldn´t that pi/4 be the integration constant and therefore my first answer be correct? I have checked my procedure for almost an hour and I´m going crazy trying to find what I did wrong/skipped. What mindblows me the most is the fact that there is $\pi/4$ inside of the answer! I´m currently taking calc 2 and I´ve done a lot of integrals and i´ve never seen an integral that gives you a constant apart from the integration constant (apart from integral of 0 ofc). I also think that´s impossible but i don´t know how to prove it. Please help

PD1: One thing I did while solving the integral was considering $\sqrt{\cos{^2}(u)}=\cos(u)$ instead of $\left| \cos(u) \right|$ but I don´t think that causes the appereance of the $+\pi/4$ at the end.

PD2: The appereance of $+\pi/4$ surprises me because I can´t think of a function $f(x)$ such that $\int_{}^{}f(x) dx=F(x)+B+C$ where only $C$ is the integration constant.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] take a [tour]. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Please do not use pictures (or link to videos) for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I will say that this is a useful tool for checking your work https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: @Marco thanks for the information and for the suggested edits!

Comment: @vallev thanks! but the website stills replaces x with sin(u), i don´t know if there is a way to tell the website to use x=cos(u)

Comment: From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title:
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so **make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title**."

Comment: @jjagmath thanks for the suggestion. hope now the question is phrased better

Comment: If WA thinks the answer with $\pi/4$ is right but the answer without is wrong, then you should report this to them as a bug.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I also thought it could be a bug but WA´s answer for the integral is $1/2(\arcsin(x)-x\sqrt{1-x{^2}})$ and when arcsin(x) is replaced with arcsin(x)=pi/2-arccos(x), the answer is $-1/2(\arccos(x)+x\sqrt{1-x{^2}})+\pi/4$ so i don´t think it´s a bug. I´m pretty sure now that it has something to do with considering sqrt(cos(u)^2)=cos(u) instead of |cos(u)|

Comment: When you say your answer is wrong according to WA, do you mean that you type in your answer and WA says "no, that's wrong"? or do you just mean that when you type in the question WA gives a different answer than the one you got? If it's the latter, that's no big deal, for some reason WA just likes to put a superfluous $\pi/4$ in there. If the former – if WA explicitly tells you you are wrong – then it's a bug, and you should report it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson When i enter $\int_{}\frac{x{^2}}{\sqrt{1-x{^2}}}dx^{}=-1/2(\arccos(x)+x\sqrt{1-x{^2}})$ in WA, the output is "False"; but when I input $\int_{}\frac{x{^2}}{\sqrt{1-x{^2}}}dx^{}=-1/2(\arccos(x)+x\sqrt{1-x{^2}})+\frac{\pi}{4}$, the output is "True". So, it´s a bug right?

Comment: I would say so, yes.

Comment: @gnzlama answering your previous message to me: you can write the substitution on paper and then input that on the site